# How to add admin user to SQL Server database that is hosted on the web(Remote Server)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to change a user to become the administrator that I have created access to sql server database from a remote server(A2 hosting). I have followed a few examples such as selecting Login>Propertoes>Server Role> changing the role to sysadmin however I receive the following error:

[image]

I have seen plenty of answers for help with local servers, but I need help with setting up admin user for a **sql server database that is hosted on the web**. Thank you!

Comment: Is this a shared host? On a shared hosting account it's unlikely that the hosting provider will allow you to become administrator of the whole server - probably other customers' databases are stored there as well. You will most likely be limited to administering the database(s) associated with your account. Why do you need an administrator account, anyway? On a shared host I doubt you need do actually do anything which needs those privileges.

Comment: i wanred to reconfigure the database that i created to have fdata with filestream, however i keep on getting the error that user logged in can not reconfigure as  the user is not logged in as admin.. you know any solution?

Comment: So again...is this a shared host? Clearly, if you are not the administrator then it is not going to let you become an administrator...that would be the worst security hole ever. So no, unless you already know the sysadmin credentials then there isn't a solution to that. You need to ask the current administrator to help you. If that happens to be your hosting company, then please contact them for support.

Comment: @JaneCohen Yes, agree with ADyson. On shared hosting, there are some rules and you can't use administrator priviledges. You better contact your hosting provider and ask about the job that you want to do.